# Create folder from filename then copy file

Tags: batch-file

This might look as a usual question here in stackflow but it's a bit different on how it operates. I got over a half-a-million+ and counting wav files which I need to sort. All files are stored in a single directory and files are named like:

---

### OUT60105-20151109-161938-144XXXXXXX.70572.WAV

This file was generated from a call on team member's Extension 60105 (OUT60125) on 20151109 (date-of-recording) and the callers Team leader name is Boyly.

---

### OUT60168-20151110-161850-144XXXXXXX.70570.WAV

This file was generated from a call on team member's Extension 60168 (OUT60168) on 20151110 (date-of-recording) and the callers Team leader is Girly.

---

### and so forth...

So with the information above, I'd like to sort all those files to a directory structure below:

**F:\Recordings\Team Leader's name\Team member's Extension\date-of-recording**

This is what I have so far and honestly, I don't know what's next to perform:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set FolderIncoming=F:\Incoming_Rec
set FileMask=OUT*.WAV
set FolderSorted=F:\Recordings\TeamLeader

for %%a in ("%FolderIncoming%\%FileMask%") do (

      Set FileName=%%~a


  for /f "tokens=1-2 delims=-" %%b in ("%%~nxa") do (                 

          if not exist "%FolderSorted%\%%e\%%b\%%~na.WAV" (
          if not exist "%FolderSorted%\%%e\%%b" md "%FolderSorted%\%%e\%%b"
          copy "%%a" "%FolderSorted%\%%e\%%b"
          )

       )
)
```

How can I go with this? Please note that I have several team leaders and on their team are several members (extensions) as well.

Comment: Indicate the "161938" the name "Boyly" and "161850" = "Girly"? How many Team leaders exist (approx)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**: *Copy only those recordings from Extension listed in the array*

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

rem Create the array of Team leader names
for %%a in ("161938=Boyly"
            "161850=Girly") do (
   for /F "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%b in (%%a) do (
      set "name[%%b]=%%c"
   )
)

set FolderIncoming=F:\Incoming_Rec
set FileMask=OUT*.WAV
set FolderSorted=F:\Recordings

for %%a in ("%FolderIncoming%\%FileMask%") do (

   for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=-" %%b in ("%%~NXa") do (

      set "leader=!name[%%d]!"

      rem Copy only those recordings from Extension listed in the array
      if defined leader (

         if not exist "%FolderSorted%\!leader!\%%b\%%c\%%~Na.WAV" (
            if not exist "%FolderSorted%\!leader!\%%b\%%c" md "%FolderSorted%\!leader!\%%b\%%c"
            copy "%%a" "%FolderSorted%\!leader!\%%b\%%c"
         )

      )

   )

)
```

You may read further details on array management in Batch files at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990).

Comment: Hi Aacini, right now I have 7 team leaders. The script executed well but it does not create the Team leader's name sub-folder. It only creates as follows: F:\Incoming_Rec\OUT60105\20151110 w/c supposedly should create F:\Incoming_Rec\Boyly\OUT60105\20151110.

Comment: I made a test in my computer and it works correctly. See the edit in my answer...

Comment: Is there a way in which the codes above will copy only those recordings from Extension listed in the array ("161938=Boyly","161850=Girly")? All other recordings not included in the array will be left out in the Folder_Incoming.